# Elastic Beanstalk - Remove Nginx version from headers

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Elastic Beanstalk for hosting my node app. In my node response I got a header that shows the **Nginx** version. For security reasons I want to remove or overwrite it.

I don't want to change anything else. I just want to remove this header only.

I also tried to send header from backend side but **Nginx** overwrites this header.

[image: Response image]

Answer (score 1):

You will need to configure the nginx to turn server headers off.
The way to configure the `nginx.conf` file for Elastic Beanstalk is described here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html

And you need to set `server_tokens off;` in the nginx configuration.
Detail of this config can be found at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_tokens

> Syntax:   server_tokens on | off | build | string;
> Default:
>
> server_tokens on;
>
> Context:  http, server, location
>
> Enables or disables emitting nginx version on error pages and in the
> “Server” response header field.